# Loop through checkboxes and conditionally disable unchecked

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to write a basic function in pure JS that simply checks the number of checked checkboxes, and if that number exceeds a certain amount, disables the rest. I can achieve this easily in jQuery, but trying to get it working in pure JS. I have a CodePen set up [here](https://codepen.io/nickpish/pen/MBvxwx) and I'm including my working JS below. Thanks for any insight here.

```
(function() {

  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="mktoCheckbox"]');
  var active = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="mktoCheckbox"]:checked');
  var numActive = active.length;

  console.log(numActive);

  if (numActive > 1) {
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
                return;
            } else {
                checkboxes[i].disabled == true;
            }
        }
  }

})();
```

Comment: You have a `return;` statement in your loop. That will exit the loop when it encounters the first checked checkbox. In your example, it's the first one, so nothing happens. Also, you are using the equality operator in the other clause of the `if` block: `checkboxes[i].disabled == true;` It should be `checkboxes[i].disabled = true;` if you want to set the property to `true`.

Comment: I suspect you may have been led astray by the fact that when using jQuery one might often use `$.each` which takes a function as an argument. In that case returning from the function would simply break out of the current iteration. `for` doesn't use a function callback but rather is an expression in it's own right, so returning will end the entire loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You're returning from the `if` condition, which causes the loop to terminate.
2. You're not assigning `true` to `disabled` attribute, instead you're comparing with `==`.

Change the related snippet to the following to make it work:

```
if (numActive > 1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked != true) {
      checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

You can find a working fork of your pen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxqZmB). Following is a working SO snippet:

```js
(function() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="mktoCheckbox"]');
  var active = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="mktoCheckbox"]:checked');
  var numActive = active.length;

  console.log(numActive);

  if (numActive > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].checked != true) {
        checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose some monster features</legend>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mktoCheckbox_1" name="feature" value="scales" checked />
    <label for="scales">Scales</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mktoCheckbox_2" name="feature" value="horns" />
    <label for="horns">Horns</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mktoCheckbox_3" name="feature" value="claws" />
    <label for="claws">Claws</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mktoCheckbox_4" name="feature" value="tails" checked />
    <label for="tails">Tails</label>
  </div>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [working pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPdEVy).

First of all, imo, you should use `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` on DOM elements. `HTMLInputElement.checked` afaik only reflects the `checked` attribute (and converts it to `boolean`) for convenience.

With that in mind, you need to now test against strings with the strict comparison operator `===`. E.g.

```
if(checkbox.getAttribute('checked') === 'true') {...}
```

since using `==` would evaluate to false

```
true == 'true' // false
```

Also, instead of the **for** loop you can make use the **for-of** loop on DOM collections. I.e. this works:

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('...');
for(const checkbox of checkboxes) {
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind that you use `continue` and `break` to control the loop and not `return`.

Comment: While `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` are vital to know in pure js `.checked` still works in this case (and may be faster)

Comment: Out of curiosity- I'm seeing this answer was downvoted; for my own edification, is there a reason that this is a less desirable/performant approach than the selected answer above?

Comment: I'm afraid I downvoted it because it wasn't really answering the question and was actually a bit misleading e.g. you can totally still use the `.checked` attribute in this case. Also I'm not exactly sure what was meant by the comment about type conversion, but it seems like they are suggesting that `true == 'true'` would resolve as false which is incorrect. The opposite is the case `true == 'true'` resolves as true while `true === 'true'` resolves as false (generally you should always use the strict equality `===` for more reliable code.)

Comment: @ChrisM I just checked this in the console in chrome and `true == 'true'` evaluates to `false`. I don't see why you would think otherwise. It's debatable whether to use `getAttribute/setAttribute` or the `checked` property. But they'r equivalent given the right test and you could argue that attribute is more standard since the `checked` property is computed from the attribute. Also, I'm in fact answering the question by providing working code?

Comment: @FK82 Right, my bad `true == 'true'` is false. I think I must have been thinking of the case with numbers ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators ) but it's a bit of a moot point in this case because so is `true === 'true'`. It's true one should make a habit of using `===` but your comment is confusing in this context. While you linked to a working example it wasn't adequately explained in the body of your answer. That in itself isn't a basis for downvoting but the body being confusing is. Sorry. I appreciate you are trying to help :)

Comment: I'm now scratching my head because I'm pretty sure there is a language somewhere where, horribly, `true == 'true'` is true but I'm not sure which. I always use '===' with JS so my assumption there was never tested. PHP perhaps? Hmm *disappears down a google hole*

Comment: @ChrisM I updated my answer to clarify the points you said were confusing. Btw, I'm pretty sure that it's ok to forget any language where true == 'true'. There's only so much type bending once can/should tolerate. ; )

Comment: @FK82 I've removed the downvote. I should perhaps be quicker to ask for clarification than simply downvote. Btw it *was* PHP but only because all non-empty strings count as true in that mad world. *screams*